# SQL replace portion of a string counting in from search result

Tags: sql, replace

I am trying to extract the ID portion (11 characters) of a bunch of different youtube embed codes. I've successfully done it in excel but the file is way too huge to reimport. Here is the excel formula I used:

```
=RIGHT(MID(E1,FIND("http",E1,1),36),11)
```

ie I want to `FIND` where the first instance of "http" starts, `SELECT` 36 characters from there and then `SELECT` the 11 characters on the `RIGHT` of the result.

THEN run a REPLACE like so...

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta set `meta_value` = replace(`meta_value`, "<original content>", "<results of query>")
where meta_key = "_youtube"
```

I'm stuck on the first part - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
   SET meta_value = RIGHT(MID(meta_value, LOCATE('http', meta_value, 1) + 4, 36), 11)
 WHERE meta_key = '_youtube';
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ef4d/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks - worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

Okay solution which worked for me was:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET `meta_value` = replace(`meta_value`, meta_value, RIGHT(SUBSTRING(meta_value,LOCATE('http', meta_value),36),11) )
WHERE meta_key = "_youtube"
```